# How to raise a dynamically created event on a dynamically created winform control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `CheckedListBox` control that I created programatically from below...

```
Button btnSelectAll = new Button();
btnSelectAll.Text = "Select All";
btnSelectAll.Name = item.Id;
btnSelectAll.Tag = param.Id;
CheckedListBox chkListBox = new CheckedListBox();
chkListBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(flowPanel.Size.Width - lblListBox.Size.Width - 10, 100);
//set the name and tag for downstream event handling since two-way bindings are not possible with control
chkListBox.Tag = param.Id;
chkListBox.Name = item.Id;
chkListBox.ItemCheck += new ItemCheckEventHandler(chkListBox_ItemCheck);
btnSelectAll.Click += new EventHandler(btnSelectAll_Click);
```

Notice when I dynamically created the item, I also added an event handler whenever the ItemCheck on the chkListBox is hit.  Somewhere else in the code... I do...

```
CheckedListBox tmpCheckedListBox = cntrl as CheckedListBox;
for (int i = 0; i < tmpCheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
   tmpCheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

When I do the above, it doens't raise the ItemChecked event.  How do I raise this event such that it is as if a user clicked on the item?

Comment: No, calling SetItemChecked() definitely raises the ItemChecked event.  Something's borken, can't see what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just call the same method as assigned to the event and pass in the correct control for sender, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tmpCheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
   tmpCheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(i, true);
   chkListBox_ItemCheck(tmpCheckedListBox.Items[i],null);
}
```

You can usually get away with passing `EventArgs.Empty` or `null` as the event arguments, however if you depend on them in the event handler you would need to construct the correct arguments class and pass that in, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tmpCheckedListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
   var args = new ItemCheckEventArgs(i,true,tmpCheckedListBox.GetItemChecked(i));

   tmpCheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(i, true);
   chkListBox_ItemCheck(tmpCheckedListBox.Items[i],args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  this worked, however after debugging it based on your recommendation I found out the problem was something else.  The original SetItemChecked method actually raises the event natively.

Comment: @Grant Thanks I was teetering for a while.